# Hiding an input button with jQuery and also firing an AJAX function with.NET

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

I have an input button for adding items to a cart. Basically the ideal situation is the user clicks the input button, it disappears, shows the loading GIF, then once the items have been added to the cart the button reappears. This is the input button:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="MainScriptManager" />
<asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="PageUpdateProgress">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <img class="ajax-loader" src="/Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading.." />
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel2" runat="server" updatemode="Always">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="AddToCart" eventname="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="AddToCart" OnClientClick="hideAddToCart" Text="Add To Cart" class="add-to-cart" ID="AddToCart" name="AddToCart" type="submit"  ></asp:Button>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here's the code behind for this:

```
protected void AddToCart(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // this loads the cart for manipulation
  Cart cart  = Cart.Load();

  if (cart.Add("Items")) //this adds items and returns a BOOL for if it succeeded or not
  {
      AddToCart.Style.Add("visibility", "visible");

  }
}
```

And here is the jQuery for the onclientclick attribute

```
/* We need to hide the "Add To Cart" button when clicked for AJAX purposes */
function hideAddToCart()
{
  $(".add-to-cart").css("visibility", "hidden");
}
```

So this works the first time you click the button. After that it stops working. I'm not too sure what the issue is.

The button will continue to add items to the cart so that works beyond the first click. The jQuery isn't firing off after the first click.

**EDIT**

This is what is rendered before I click the button the first time:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ItemDetails$ItemDetails$ctl00$ChildItems$ChildItems$FooterTemplate$AddToCart" value="Add To Cart" onclick="hideAddToCart;" id="MainContent_ItemDetails_ItemDetails_ChildItems_0_ChildItems_0_AddToCart" class="add-to-cart">
```

Then I click it:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ItemDetails$ItemDetails$ctl00$ChildItems$ChildItems$FooterTemplate$AddToCart" value="Add To Cart" onclick="hideAddToCart;" id="MainContent_ItemDetails_ItemDetails_ChildItems_0_ChildItems_0_AddToCart" class="add-to-cart" style="visibility:visible;">
```

Comment: $(".add-to-cart").css("visibility", "hidden") <  $(".add-to-cart").hide()

Comment: @MarcusH forgot .hide() existed. Still doesn't fix my problem though.

Comment: After your code has postback and the AddToCart.Style.Add("visibility", "visible"); is set. What property is enabled in the html button? Looks to me that asp sets a different value then your javascript.

Comment: @MarcusH Just updated the OP. From what I can tell is the only thing that is different is now it has the visibility:visible inline style added.

Comment: I would try adding !important to the hidden value: 

    function hideAddToCart()
{
  $(".add-to-cart").css("visibility", "hidden !important");
}

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I solved the issue. The OnClientClick was expecting () at the end of my function, hence why rendering the button added a semicolon to the end of the OnClientClick attribute.

**ASP button code**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="AddToCart_Child" OnClientClick="hideAddToCart()" Text="Add To Cart" class="add-to-cart test" ID="AddToCart" name="AddToCart" type="submit"  ></asp:Button>
```

**OnClientClick** needs () for calling functions.